# How to avoid duplication of tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a system simple tags box, the problem is that if I add the same word,

**Example:**

php, and php,

the label is duplicated with the same word.

Code complete.

```js
$(function(){ // DOM ready

  // ::: TAGS BOX

  $("#tags input").on({
    focusout : function() {
      var txt = this.value.replace(/[^a-z0-9\+\-\.\#]/ig,''); // allowed characters
      if(txt) $("<span/>", {text:txt.toLowerCase(), insertBefore:this});
      this.value = "";
    },
    keyup : function(ev) {
      // if: comma|enter (delimit more keyCodes with | pipe)
      if(/(188|13)/.test(ev.which)) $(this).focusout(); 
    }
  });
  $('#tags').on('click', 'span', function() {
    $(this).remove(); 
  });

});
```

```css
#tags{
  float:left;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  padding:5px;
  font-family:Arial;
}
#tags > span{
  cursor:pointer;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  color:#fff;
  background:#789;
  padding:5px;
  padding-right:25px;
  margin:4px;
}
#tags > span:hover{
  opacity:0.7;
}
#tags > span:after{
 position:absolute;
 content:"×";
 border:1px solid;
 padding:2px 5px;
 margin-left:3px;
 font-size:11px;
}
#tags > input{
  background:#eee;
  border:0;
  margin:4px;
  padding:7px;
  width:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tags">
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Add a tag" />
</div>
```

the only problem is the duplication of the label (**tags**), to the add a word same like.

Comment: What would you like to happen when the user tries to add a duplicate tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could maintain an array of tag values that you check against before creating new tag elements. A message is shown if the user tries to enter a duplicate tag and the message is removed if the user removes a tag or successfully adds a new tag:

```js
$(function() { // DOM ready

  // ::: TAGS BOX

  var tags = [];

  $("#tags input").on({
    focusout: function() {
      var txt = this.value.replace(/[^a-z0-9\+\-\.\#]/ig, ''); // allowed characters
      if (txt) {
        // Check if array contains value before creating span
        if ((tags.indexOf(txt) === -1)) {
          $('#message').hide();
          $("<span/>", {
            text: txt.toLowerCase(),
            insertBefore: this
          });
        } else {
          $('#message').show();
        }
      }
      tags.push(txt);
      this.value = "";
    },
    keyup: function(ev) {
      // if: comma|enter (delimit more keyCodes with | pipe)
      if (/(188|13)/.test(ev.which)) $(this).focusout();
    }
  });
  $('#tags').on('click', 'span', function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    // Filter tag array on tag removal
    tags = tags.filter(function(e) {
      return e !== text;
    });
    $('#message').hide();
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

```css
#tags {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
#tags > span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  background: #789;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  margin: 4px;
}
#tags > span:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
#tags > span:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "×";
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
#tags > input {
  background: #eee;
  border: 0;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 7px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tags">
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Add a tag" />
</div>
<p id="message" style="display:none">You cannot create a duplicate tag.</p>
```

Comment: Perfect friend. But not be better to show an error message automatically or it's better?

Comment: @Paul I've updated the code to include a message and I've updated the explanation. You should edit your question to state that you want a message if the user tries to add a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you friend :)

Comment: I have a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427511/as-adding-error-message-and-add-tags-to-the-database) on the same subject help me :)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this please.** It just checks whether the same tag exists before adding it. You can add error message too if you want in the else clause.

```js
$(function(){ // DOM ready

  // ::: TAGS BOX

  $("#tags input").on({
    focusout : function() {
      var txt = this.value.replace(/[^a-z0-9\+\-\.\#]/ig,''); // allowed characters
      if(txt && !$("#tags span:contains("+ txt.toLowerCase() +")").length) {
        
        $("<span/>", {text:txt.toLowerCase(), insertBefore:this});
        this.value = "";
      }
    },
    keyup : function(ev) {
      // if: comma|enter (delimit more keyCodes with | pipe)
      if(/(188|13)/.test(ev.which)) $(this).focusout(); 
    }
  });
  $('#tags').on('click', 'span', function() {
    $(this).remove(); 
  });

});
```

```css
#tags{
  float:left;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  padding:5px;
  font-family:Arial;
}
#tags > span{
  cursor:pointer;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  color:#fff;
  background:#789;
  padding:5px;
  padding-right:25px;
  margin:4px;
}
#tags > span:hover{
  opacity:0.7;
}
#tags > span:after{
 position:absolute;
 content:"×";
 border:1px solid;
 padding:2px 5px;
 margin-left:3px;
 font-size:11px;
}
#tags > input{
  background:#eee;
  border:0;
  margin:4px;
  padding:7px;
  width:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tags">
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Add a tag" />
</div>
```

Comment: @Paul did you try it?

Comment: Perfect friend. You can include a message so automatically when adding or you type a label equal. displaying an error message or warning.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem

```
$("#tags input").on({
    focusout: function () {
        //append text(sugsession :Not use append process.Use html() like replace existing content method.)
    },
    keyup: function (ev) {
            ....$(this).focusout();
    }
});
```

Seems focusout is fire twice.keyup also calling focusout event.Seems it is append like method.

Suggesion

append vs html

use html method.You have to define a extra div to hold that dynamic content.It it wont concat.It won't depend on method number of occurence that method invoked.

```
$("#newDiv").html(txt.toLowerCase());
```

use above instead of bellow
    if (txt) $("", {
        text: txt.toLowerCase(),
        insertBefore: this
    });

[reference 1](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_set)
[reference 2](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_append_ref)